# Can any mac device can be upgraded to Mac OS 10.6.x?

Tags: mac

Can any mac device like Power Book G4, Mac Mini etc. be upgraded to Mac OS version 10.6.x?

Comment: Arkaaito is right, read the right hand column [on the Apple site](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html) and you'll see that any intel cpu will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

[Apple states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard#System_requirements) the following basic Snow Leopard system requirements are:

- Mac computer with an Intel processor (IA-32). "Yonah" processors such as Core Solo and Core Duo can run only 32-bit applications; later x86-64 architecture processors such as Core 2 Duo will also be able to run 64-bit applications.
- 1 GB of RAM
- 5 GB of free disk space
- DVD drive (also accessible via Remote Disc) or external USB or FireWire DVD drive for installation

Answer (score 0):

10.6.x (Snow Leopard) can be installed on any Intel-based Mac, and [not on PowerPC-based Macs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard).  PowerBooks are the latter.

Comment: -1: This is not true, if the computer doesn't meet the specs mentioned by @KevinBallard, you can't upgrade it.